# Играть в бильярд или играть на бильярде?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Часто можно слышать выражение "играть на бильярде". Но, честно говоря, мне оно кажется устаревшим.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли говорить "играть на бильярде" или все-таки нужно "играть в бильярд"? Все-таки бильярд - это игра, а не музыкальный инструмент, поэтому играют в него, как в футбол или шахматы, а не на нем, как на рояле или арфе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Бильярд - это название игры и сам специальный стол для нее.

> Толковый словарь русского языка (Ожегов С., Шведова Н)
> **Бильярд**
> 1. Игра на специальном столе, при к-рой ударами кия шары загоняются в лузы. Играть в бильярд. Партия в бильярд. 2. Стол с бортами и лузами для этой игры. **Играть на бильярде**. || прил. бильярдный, -ая,-ое.

Поэтому возможны оба варианта : *играть в/на ...*